# C++ fake/mock return value based on the value of parameter

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, typemock

Using Typemock Isolator++.
Is it possible that the returning value from a fake method is based on the value of parameter?

for example:

```
WHEN_CALLED(student->GradeOfCourse("a")).ReturnVal(70);
WHEN_CALLED(student->GradeOfCourse("b")).ReturnVal(85);
```

then if the parameter is ("a"), it will return 70.

and if the parameter is ("b") then it will return 85.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer I work in Typemock

Use `DoMemberFunctionInstead` or `DoStaticOrGlobalInstead` to redirect your call to an alternative method - there you can return a differnet value based on the value of parameter.

Add this method

```
int FakeGradeOfCourse(char * name)
{
   if (strcmp(name,"a")==0)
   {
      return 70;
   }
   return 85;
 }
```

In your test call:

```
WHEN_CALLED(student->GradeOfCourse(_)).
   DoStaticOrGlobalInstead(FakeGradeOfCourse, NULL);
```

You can find an example for this in our [docs](http://docs.typemock.com/Isolatorpp/##ippHelp.chm/doinstead_behavior.htm).